# Is 'Juice' Singular or Plural In This Sentence?

Tags: grammatical-number

### "How much juice can you afford?"

I am confused by this because it is asking about the quantity of juice that can be bought. How would one know if it is referring to a single container of juice or multiple containers? For the latter, would one have to ask instead, "How **many juices** can you afford?" Could it be either, depending on the context?

Comment: Both noncount and obviously count ('Two orange juices, please') usages are clearly described at [OLD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/juice_1). Though 'juices' for 'cartons of juice [bought at a supermarket, say]' is probably rarer than when buying juices, beers, lagers etc for consumption on-site.

Comment: For an overview, see John Lawler's answer at [What is the logic behind uncountable nouns?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/202626/what-is-the-logic-behind-uncountable-nouns/202636#202636). This contains: 'In addition to this conventional countification of mass nouns, indicating varieties,
there is also a conventional massification of count nouns, indicating essence.

_You get a lot of car for your money when you buy X._ // 
_After the bomb he ate went off, there was Godzilla all over Times Square._'

Comment: You need to provide the source, and the context if there is any. In any case it's usually **how much** for beverages: How much coffee do we have left? How much milk did he drink last night? BUT in a restaurant setting: How many [cups of] coffees did they order?

Comment: @Mari-Lou 'How many coffees [cups of coffee] did they order?'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  Yes, instead of saying *How many cups of coffee*, it can be shortened to "*How many coffees*... "

Comment: But your signalled alternatives are 'How many cups of coffees [/coffees]'.